# Why would someone use multiplication by float instead of division

Tags: c++, c

Reading code from a program I'm newly contributing to, I found out that division was almost never used, in favor or multiplication by floats.

One exemple would be when trying to average to floats such as:

```
float a = 0.42;
float b = 0.666;

float c = (a + b) * 0.5;
```

Clearly the intent is to divide by two to average `a` and `b`

However, altho simple I find the use of `* 0.5` slightly harmful for readability (especially semantic) compared to the following:

```
float c = (a + b) / 2;
```

Which produce the exact same result.

Is there any reason why I would want to use `* 0.5` instead of `/ 2` in this case ?

Proposed duplicate indicate that multiplication is faster; which becomes obviously false if any optimisation level is used (And yes, we do compile with optimisations)

Question is about c++ but other languages answers could be helpful too.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the dup. While it does gives away a difference between multiplication and division, it does not include and advantage to use multiplication vs division.

Comment: (apart from "I'm trying to do my compiler optimization job")

Comment: If you're not satisfied with the dupe, improve and elaborate your question.

Comment: Some answers state that multiplication by inverse and division might give different results due to precision of float. So, it is not just optimization.

Comment: When division by exact powers of 2 constants are involved, both / and * by reciprocal are equivalent. Otherwise, rounding will give different results for both, and compilers will NOT optimize the / even at O3 unless the "fast" or "unsafe" optimizations are enabled (and doing so for a whole file is blunt and possibly dangerous if you require exact IEEE 754 semantics to be obeyed elsewhere in it). So the multiplication *orders* the compiler to use this different result, because the programmer judges the loss of accuracy to be acceptable, and the compiler cannot make this determination itself.

Comment: "(apart from "I'm trying to do my compiler optimization job")" -> While that's most of it, there's a coding consistency issue. It would be wierd to code division by constant as division for some constants and multiplication for others. Using division should be a signal in the code that we *really do need* a division there.

Comment: Another common reason for explicitly spelling out optimizations in general is that an unfortunate number of popular modern compilers are frankly _awful_ at generating code at intermediate and debugger-friendly optimization levels. This may then results in impractically slow or large unoptimized debug builds, consider an embedded real-time application with a hard time/space envelope regardless of the build, unless some optimization is applied by hand.

Answer (score 1):

For most cases this just comes down to personal preference or general coding style. Say we are changing values a lot just to fiddle around with the output values when messing with a function to see how it behaves. Then, since the values may change, multiplying by a float makes it easier to just change to a number that wouldn't make sense to write as division.

Also, one advantage to multiplying by a float is it can help avoid the truncation towards zero that can mistakenly happen when dividing two ints.